# Unable to access endpoint on flask api

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I am trying to build an api with flask and flask-restplus, it seems fine with no errors. When I launch the server, it look fine like this [image: app]
but whatever the uri, I try to test, it displays `requested URL was not found on the server` and do know how to run the correspondent resource.
this is a sample of my code

```
   @api.route('/')
   class UserList(Resource):
    @api.doc('list_of_registered_users')
    @admin_token_required
    @api.marshal_list_with(_user, envelope='data')
    def get(self):
     """List all registered users"""
     logger.debug('Hello from webapplib!')
     return userService.get_all()

    @api.expect(_user, validate=True)
    @api.response(201, 'User successfully created.')
    @api.doc('create a new user')
    def post(self):
     """Creates a new User """
     data = request.json
     return save_new_user(data=data)
```

Comment: Are you sure you accessed your URL correctly? There's a difference between `/user` and `/user/`

Comment: I don't have access neither `/user` nor `/user/`

Comment: Are your endpoints defined correctly in the flask-app? Could it be a typo? Are they perhaps redirecting somewhere else that doesn't exist? Is there a GET endpoint for what you are trying to access? Also, for your and other people's sanity: please indent your code with more than one single space. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recommends four spaces.

Comment: thank, @OliverBaumann, how can i add pep 8 in my vscode

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting might be worth a shot. I don't use that IDE myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but maybe it is *that* simple.

I assume you were accessing `/user`. In your code-sample, the decorator for `UserList` is `@api.route('/')`, which corresponds to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` when running flask in the dev-server (maybe with some API-versioning path appendend, but let's ignore that for now).

Have you tried just decorating that with `@api.route('/user')` instead of just `/`?